# How to get the length of an integer in Java (Android)

Tags: android, onclicklistener, variable-length

So if I had the value 1234 the output should be 4.

I've written the following code, but don't know what I did wrong.
This is an App, that adds two numbers. So I've got two EditTextfields. But if an EditTextfield is left blank, the App crashes.
So I thought of assigning the value of 0 to an EditTextfield, that has been left blank, because it (should) have a character length of 0.

That should get the right results:

Example, if EditTextfield "firstnumET" holds a value of 5 and "secondnumET" is left blank:

5 + 0 = 5

The problem might be

---

```
private int firstnum;
private int secondnum;
private int total;


EditText firstnumET;
EditText secondnumET;
TextView ansTV;
Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cal2_numbers);


    firstnumET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt1);
    secondnumET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt2);
    ansTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);


    button.setOnClickListener(new ClickButton());



}

    private class ClickButton implements Button.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        firstnum = Integer.parseInt(firstnumET.getText().toString());
        secondnum = Integer.parseInt(secondnumET.getText().toString());

        int cache1 = Integer.toString(firstnum).length();
        int cache2 = Integer.toString(secondnum).length();
        if (cache1 == 0) {
            ansTV.setText(Integer.toString(secondnum));
        }
        if (cache2 == 0) {
            ansTV.setText(Integer.toString(firstnum));
        }



        total = firstnum + secondnum;

        ansTV.setText(Integer.toString(total));
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too long for a comment, why don't you check your strings and then set them based on their length if they aren't empty.

```
String firstString = firstnumET.getText().toString();
firstNum = (firstString.trim().equals(""))? 0: firstString.length();

String secondString = secondnumET.getText().toString();
secondNum = (secondString.trim().equals(""))? 0: secondString.length();

ansTV.setText(Integer.toString(firstNum + secondNum));
```

You could obviously make it more complex than that, checking to make sure the string contains only numerical values so that you make sure you aren't getting the length of a non-numeric string.

String.trim removes white space, this helps avoid an edit text filled with spaces.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using both String.length() and Integer.parseInt()?  I'm pretty sure length() can only return an integer.

Comment: @camdroid Wrote the solution really quick and made a dumb mistake :P

Comment: EditText.getText().toString() returns null if nothing is entered, not "".  Your ?: statements will always evaluate false.

Comment: getText() actually never returns null. It returns super class CharSequence and it returns text which is initialized as "" in constructor.

Comment: Looks like a bug I encountered some time ago was not caused by what I thought it was.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
secondnum = Integer.parseInt(secondnumET.getText().toString());
```

If this is left blank, secondnumET.getText().toString() will return null.

Here's a better way to accomplish what you're attempting.

```
public void onClick(View v) {


    String firstnum = firstnumET.getText().toString();
    String secondnum = secondnumET.getText().toString();

    int cache1 = firstnum.equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(firstnum);
    int cache2 = secondnum.equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(secondnum);
    total = firstnum + secondnum;

    ansTV.setText(Integer.toString(total).length());  // set the answer to the length of total
    ansTV.setText(Integer.toString(total));  // set the answer to total
}
```

Comment: firstnum and secondnum will never equal null. That isn't how getText works. And parsing the int will return the value of the string, not it's length. Made that error myself on my first post.

Comment: You appear to be correct.  I was getting a NullPointerException in an app and adding a check for null solved it, but it must've solved it for a different reason.  Off to check my code...

Comment: definitely done that before, the joys of programming :P